# How to send a message to a queue if pipeline crashes

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-beam

I have an apache beam pipeline that accepts messages then saves the message to a queue or database. If saving to Cassandra fails due to database failure or other issues how would I save the original message to a different queue? Here is how I am creating the pipeline

```
public Pipeline pipelineDirectRunner() {
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        options.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);
        return  Pipeline.create(options);
}
```

Comment: Not sure about Cassandra specifically. But if an IO doesn't handle the exceptions and just crashes then there is no easy way to do it. If you cannot find a solution, as a workaround, you can write your own "IO", by writing a ParDo where you manually call any service using its native client and not using the IO. In this case you can handle all the exceptions or custom logic.

Comment: In case of CassandraIO I am not seeing an option to handle it, maybe I am missing. What I see is the Write is a ParDo calls Mutator.mutate: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c38666a5bf854e7b36612d53de370f8f0d3fbf5c/sdks/java/io/cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraIO.java#L1010 and it can throw exceptions: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c38666a5bf854e7b36612d53de370f8f0d3fbf5c/sdks/java/io/cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraIO.java#L1113 and none of this has any logic to customize this flow